# Running program in IntelliJ J problems with insert data to scanner

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I have one problem with IntelliJ
I have program in Java(grade) I have good program with scanners. Program run correctly but don't as input data for scanner....What can I do? It is something with setting of IntelliJ?
Process finished with exit code 0 but don't ask for inert data....

I suppose it is something with IntelliJ?

Comment: I apologise I have it ....I didn't run program from main ....That was the reason....When I run program from main everything work correctly

Comment: Hard to help you without minimal, reproducible example

Comment: Thank you I solved it.....I working on simple bot chat on Hyperskill....and the problem was that i wasn't on the right part of code....Thank you for your interest